# Poor anti aliasing of 3D model using XNA in Silverlight, how to fix?

Tags: silverlight, 3d, xna, antialiasing

In Silverlight, I am embedding a 3D model using XNA. The model is rendered in a DrawingSurface control.
The issue I am having is that the model render is quite poor in quality.
The model has jagged edges even with anti aliasing turned on (see code below), and the model is also blurry.

```
Dim comp As New OffscreenCompositionMode
    comp.PreferredMultiSampleCount = 4
    comp.RenderTargetUsage = RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents
    comp.PreferredDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24

    drawingSurfaceCtl.CompositionMode = comp
```

I tried adjusting the multiSampleCount, camera position, lens and etc but to no effect.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve Anti Aliasing?

Also note that this is designed as an out of browser app on pc, and the xna game library cannot be used in this solution.

Thanks

Comment: This may be because there is no background (color), or the anti-aliasing is suppressed by some option. It could give us more information if you included a few screenshots.

Comment: There is a background colour, tried white, grey, black etc. If I turn off anti aliasing, then the model is extremely jagged.

Comment: So the antialiasing works, but you get an unsatisfactory result? And also the texture is very blurry? Sounds like your model or source picture is very small, and extrapolating it to the size of your display messes it all up.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution accidentally, the DrawingSurface control was embedded within a canvas, which in turn was embedded within a Grid. The canvas had a height and width specified which was larger than the grid row which also had a height and width specified.

So correcting the canvas height and width, and also setting a height and width to the DrawingSurface control instantly fixed the issue.

Note that I also tried various sizes for the DrawingSurface and found that a size roughly 2x the size of the canvas it was embedded in gave the best resolution.

Hope this helps anyone who has this bizarre issue!